# How to start a timer on onTouchStart and end it on onTouchEnd?

Tags: reactjs, timer, touch-event

I'm working with React and I need to continuously run a function while there is a touch event. I don't need a long touch event: the function needs to run as soon as the user touches the screen and should stop being called when the user stops touching the screen.

I need the possibility for the user to move the touching point around without stopping the background function execution.

I would need something like a "touchDown" listener that triggers if the screen is being touched. Think of a stopwatch, where the user has to keep a finger on the screen to make the timer run and stops running when the user releases the touch.

It seems that setInterval does not work as it stops while the user moves the touching point around. I did not find any really good help in the web...Any suggestion?

Comment: What is `setTimeInterval`? Did you mean `setInterval`? `setInterval` doesn't stop until you call `clearInterval`

Comment: Yeah sorry I'll edit the question. SetInterval *does* stop when onTouchMove is called.

Comment: No it doesn't https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-shadow-lnheht?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm trying to update a state within SetInterval and my code does not work. I guess I'm not using the useRef hook correctly